# FabricJS - How to rotate Rectangle with Clipped Image at same time

Tags: fabricjs

I have a component with two elements Rect and image. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is by rotating RED element (Rect) it's clipped image should also rotate by the container's angle + initial image angle and vice versa.

My question is how to make the image be dependable on its container and vice versa without grouping them?

*** Rotation of image must be based on container's origin point of rotation***

[JS FIDDLER](https://fiddle.jshell.net/redlive/uycy5f6h/24/)

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/using-transformations)

Comment: Awesome... Tnx !